# Introducing new hypothesis in the premises

Tags: coq

My current goals are following:

```
  n' : nat
  IHn' : forall m : nat, n' + n' = m + m -> n' = m
  m' : nat
  H1 : n' + n' = m' + m'
  ============================
   S n' = S m'
```

Now, I want to `apply H1` in `IHn'` such that the following hypothesis is introduced:

```
n' = m'
```

I have tried this:

```
apply H1 with (m := m') in IHn'.
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Error: No such bound variable m.
```

This is the complete reproducible program with those goals:

```
Theorem my_theorem : forall n m,
     n + n = m + m -> n = m.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n as [| n'].
  - simpl. 
    intros m H.
    symmetry in H.
    destruct m as [| m'].
    + reflexivity.
    + rewrite -> plus_Sn_m in H.
      inversion H.
  - simpl.
    rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.
    intros m.
    intros H.
    destruct m as [| m'].
    + simpl in H.
      inversion H.
    + rewrite -> plus_Sn_m in H.
      rewrite <- plus_n_Sm in H.
      inversion H.
Abort.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you had your `apply` backwards.  You need to write `apply IHn' with (m := m') in H1.`  Note that in this case it is safe to omit the `with (m := m')` clause, since Coq is smart enough to figure out that information on its own.